# how to show count on top of world map

Tags: r

**The sample code in R**

```
library(googleVis)
Geo=gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar="Country", 
                 colorvar="Profit",
                 options=list(projection="kavrayskiy-vii"))
plot(Geo)
```

the output 
[image]

Now I want to show profit count on top of the countries which is coming on hover, I want to show it in PDF so do anyone know how I can do it, please let me know if it is possible in other package like plotly or any other language like Python, Java etc

Comment: afaik there are no interactive pdf files

Comment: I don't want interactive pdf file, I just want to show same information in 2D like we do with histogram, number count on top of bin